# Is there a way to remove the mud / dirt flavour note from freshwater fish

Tags: fish

Often we buy farmed freshwater fish from the supermarket, but sometimes it has a "muddy" dirt note to the flavour.  Nearly always with [barramundi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barramundi).

Is there a way to remove this flavour?

Already I have tried to cover it with stronger flavours (like grilling (broiling) with 50:50 miso + mayonnaise on top... *drool*).  This is only partially successful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually the muddy flavor is from farmed fish that grow up in overly polluted water, although [that's not always the case](https://www.eatsustainable.co/why-do-some-fish-have-a-mud-taste/).  But that does suggest that you might be able to prevent the muddy flavor by finding barramundi from a different provider.

Soaking the fish filet in a mix of water/vinegar, water/salt, water/soda, or in milk are all suggested ways to reduce the muddy flavor.  However, none of these seem to work reliably, especially if you're soaking fish that is already a couple of days old by the time you buy it.

Beyond that, the only solution is to cook the fish in very strong-flavored sauces that will cover up the taste.

Comment: **2-Methylisoborneol**! Delicious!  /s

Comment: Isn't it not advisable to just "cover up the taste", especially if it is due to **overly polluted water**? Shouldn't health and safety come first before taste?

Comment: @user21820 "Polluted" is perhaps not the clearest term. FuzzyChef is talking about high levels of algae in the water, not heavy metals or anything. It's not a matter of safety.

Comment: @Sneftel: Thanks, then maybe a better word is "dirtied". On the other hand, it's not just algae; this happens when [fish are over-crowded with no water flow, causing leftover food and fish feces to accumulate](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2023/10/231019111003.htm). I don't know whether that affects the consumers...

Comment: @user21820 It's not a food safety concern.

Comment: @Sneftel: Great!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to get into "this can be because of natural mud and algae, but it can also be caused by agricultural runoff or feces" because that's a whole long discussion, and doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get live fish then you can keep it in clean fresh water for a day or so, or at least overnight (it also depends on the size of the fish). My first husband was a keen angler and he often brought carp or catfish home (quite remarkable monsters weighing 10 or more kg). We used to fill a tub in our second bathroom and let the water slowly flow. A carp or catfish will survive a car ride home if wrapped in a wet blanket or kept in a barrel. I know it is not very practical, but it worked for us.